# Select from Excel Sheet using OLEDB Adapter

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdataadapter

I'm using the code below to access an Excel Sheet, but the adapter.Fill always throws an exception that the sheet could not be found.

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\ImportSheet.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";";
  var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SheetName]", connectionString);
  var ds = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");
```

I verified the path for the file and the sheetname, but i'm not sure why i keep getting this error. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: [SheetName$]   add the dollar sign after the name of the sheet

Comment: Try "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]"

Comment: @Steve beat me by 16 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[SheetName$]` add the dollar sign after the name of the sheet – Steve

Try `"SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]"` – danijepg